# I put UIView.animateWithDuration in viewWillAppear but it runs only during first entrance to the panel - why?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uianimation

I try to animate a background in my swift ios app. I have an `UIImageView` with `UIImage` and I have the following method:

```
func slideImage(){

    // Changes constant to be equal to the image width,
    // this will move the image off-screen on the left-hand side.
    backgroundImageConstraint.constant = backgroundPhoto.size.width

    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: [.CurveLinear, .Repeat], animations: {
        // Animates the constant change
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: {
            done in

            // Resets the image view back to its original position before starting a new round of the animation
            self.backgroundImageConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    })
}
```

I call this method in the `viewWillAppear` function, so I expected to run it every time when user enters my panel. However that's not how it works here - I see that it is invoked only once, when I enter the panel for the 2nd time the image in the background is not scrolling. This is a weird behavior. In my `viewDidLoad` I set all the things related to the `UIImage`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    backgroundImage.image = backgroundPhoto
    backgroundImage.frame = CGRect(x: backgroundImage.frame.origin.x, y: backgroundImage.frame.origin.y, width: backgroundPhoto.size.width, height: backgroundPhoto.size.height)
    backgroundImage.contentMode = .Center
}
```

Does anyone knows why my photo is sliding only when user enters the panel for the first time and in other cases it is a static image?

Comment: FYI - if you are going to post another question taking the code of an answer from your previous question, you should up vote or accept that other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I'm gonna answer my own question - I found the information somewhere that if something interrupts the animations, the closure gets called automatically. So I moved calling the function `slideImage()` from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear` and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The `animateWithDuration` method is changing the frame of your background image moving it from the frame you set in `viewDidLoad` to the frame you have set (probably in your storyboard, with constraints). After your backgroundImage has been animated, it's frame changes and the next time you execute `slideImage()` method, the frame will be already changed, so it won't animate.

Try putting this two lines

```
backgroundImage.frame = CGRect(x: backgroundImage.frame.origin.x, y: backgroundImage.frame.origin.y, width: backgroundPhoto.size.width, height: backgroundPhoto.size.height)
backgroundImage.contentMode = .Center
```

before calling `slideImage()` in `viewWillAppear` and let us know the result.

Comment: That didn't work, now when I come back to the panel I don't see my photo at all - this is super weird..

Comment: I realized that this problem happens when I jump fast enough between the panels... when I do it slowly the photo scrolls, otherwise not. Seems like there is some problem with threads maybe or with entering the completion block in time...